# Can select many disjoint pairs with prescribed differences from Z_n?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Suppose we have a sequence $d_i<2n$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and we want to select $n$ disjoint pairs from $Z_p$, $x_i,y_i$ such that $x_i-y_i=d_i \mod p$. Then how big $p$ has to be compared to $n$ to do this? I am primary interested on an upper bound on $p$. Is it true that there is always a $p\le (1+\epsilon)2n+O(1)$?

My comments. It is trivial that $p\ge 2n$ because all the numbers $x_i,y_i$ must be different and $d_1=1, d_2=2$ shows that this is not always enough. I also guess that it helps if $p$ is a prime, maybe the smallest prime bigger than $2n$ works which would answer the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your last guess is correct. The smallest prime number $>2n$ works, see [Preissmann, Emmanuel; Mischler, Maurice
Seating couples around the King's table and a new characterization of prime numbers.
Amer. Math. Monthly 116 (2009), no. 3, 268--272.]

Comment: See also N. Alon, Additive Latin transversals, Isreal J. Math. 117 (2000) 125--130.

Comment: See also Mezei for an extension to working mod 2p: http://web.cs.elte.hu/blobs/diplomamunkak/msc_mat/2013/mezei_tamas_robert.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For those who are not afraid of a little spanish, here is a short proof using Nullstellensatz pointed to me by Preissmann, Emmanuel:
http://grupofundamental.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/il-faut-exiger-de-chacun-ce-que-chacun-peut-donner/

And yet another proof (or in fact two) which even generalizes a bit:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1177

Comment: And if you are afraid, just ask for a translation! I'm sure the authors would not mind doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see the first proof that Domotorp pointed out
http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2571 (in english)