# Number of sets of distinct pairs which doesn't share difference

Tags: co.combinatorics

Inspired by [This question by Vidyarthi](https://mathoverflow.net/q/390297/156029) I tried to find the value of $T(2m)$ where, $T(2m)$ is the number of sets of distinct pairings (so, the sets have $m$ elements) of the numbers $1,2,3....,2m$ such that for no two pairs of a set $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ $|a-b|=|c-d|$. But I couldn't find any reasonable way to solve it. Any answers and comments are welcome.

$T(2m)$ is odd. Because, for a set $(a_1,a_2);(a_3,a_4);....;(a_{2m-1},a_{2m})$ we can swap $a_i$ by $2m+1-a_i$ for all $i$. So there is a dual set for each set of pairs except for $\{(1,2m);(2,2m-1);...;(m-1,m+1)\}$ whose swapped-pair is this itself.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A060963

Comment: @RobPratt, Thank you.